# How to create a drop down list in Input Box?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I created `Browser.inputBox` which accepts only a single text. However I need to make a drop down list where I can choose from the list instead of typing the string myself.

A screenshot of the inputBox I created on clicking Odoo (in menu bar)>Settings:

[image: A screenshot of the inputBox]

Here is the function that is being triggered:

```
function menu_settings(params) {
  if (!params){
    params = [["url", "URL"], ["dbname", "Database Name"], ["username", "username"], ["password", "password"]];
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
    var input = Browser.inputBox("Server Settings", params[i][1], Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    if (input === "cancel"){
      break;
    }
    else{
      ScriptProperties.setProperty(params[i][0], input);
    }
  }
}
```

Basically **instead of typing the text, I need a drop list with predefined values.**

I was checking the [Browser class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser?hl=en) and I saw there is no such drop down list option. Most solutions that I have seen use DataValidation from texts input in the cells. But I want to give the list for the dropdown in my code and nothing on the spreadsheet.

How do I implement this?

Comment: Instead of `Browser.inputBox` use `htmlService` do display a `modelessDialog` with a select on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the code to open an HTML dialog:

```
function fncOpenMyDialog() {
  //Open a dialog
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML_myHtml')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'A Title Goes Here');
};
```

You need an HTML file.

### HTML_myHtml.html

```
<select name="nameYouWant">
  <option value="something">Text</option>
  <option value="anything">Drop Down Selection</option>
</select>

<hr/>
<ul>
  <li>This is a list.</li>
  <li>This is line two.</li>

</ul>

<button onmouseup="closeDia()">Close</button>

<script>
  window.closeDia = function() {
    google.script.host.close();
  };
</script>
```